# Bootstrap 4 navbar-toggler does not work

Tags: bootstrap-4, nav

I just try on bootstrap 4 navbar toggler function, but there is no response to the toggle button(Official site demo works well), neither does dropdown function. The following is my script, every bit is the same as demo. Any advice welcome!

BTW, the browser caught an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at util.js:68
    at util.js:10
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6

{% load bootstrap4 %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Nav Test</title>
        {% bootstrap_css %}
        {% bootstrap_javascript %}

    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"/>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"/>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you include jQuery?

Comment: Just added as your advice, but I suppose there is still something missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call jQuery and also popper before bootstrap js file. check the link below to know how to call them.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js

Comment: thank you for your advice, I added those to the bottom of my code(as above), nothing magical happened, in sad mood :-(

Comment: Finally, I digged out the exact cause behind it,  after I replaced bootstrap 4 css and js with bootstrap 4-beta ones, everything worked well, thank you, guys.:-)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem after update to bootstrap 4.1, i fix the button in production calling js in button, and remove all other properties:

```
            <button onclick="$('#navbar-main-collapse-1').toggleClass('collapse')"
                  type='button'>
          <i aria-hidden='true' class='fa fa-bars'/>
        </button>
```